# re.findall return duplicate matches

Tags: python, regex

I construct such a pattern object

```
text_regex = re.compile(r"""(
(\w+)
)""", re.UNICODE|re.VERBOSE)
```

I tried:

```
In [75]: text_regex.findall("put returns between paragraphs")
Out[75]: 
[('put', 'put'),
 ('returns', 'returns'),
 ('between', 'between'),
 ('paragraphs', 'paragraphs')]
```

It return double matches.

If I keep the enclosing `()`,
How could avoid the duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra set of parenthesis from the regex:

```
text_regex = re.compile(r"""(\w+)""", re.UNICODE|re.VERBOSE)
text_regex.findall("put returns between paragraphs")
```

Yields

```
['put', 'returns', 'between', 'paragraphs']
```

You were getting a list of tuples because, as the [findall documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) states:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

So, if you want a group but don't want a capture group use `(?:PATTERN)` instead of just `(PATTERN)` as noted in the [regular expression documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups).

Comment: And if you (for whatever reason) need the parens, but don't want to trigger capturing groups, use `(?:PATTERN)` instead of `(PATTERN)`; `(?:` begins a non-capturing group.

Comment: could you please leave an answer. @ShadowRanger